# How to avoid fraudulent User activity to gain reputation?

Tags: discussion

I just went to badges page and noticed the a badge was awarded to a person twice in a short notice. So i just checked those questions and found the votes on that answer is exactly the votes required to get the badge.

I checked the 'Voting Corrected' FAQ and its related to a user who either upvote or downvote another users answers/question will get adjusted.

So my concern is if a user could create 5 to 10 accounts and use a primary account to answer and other accounts to just vote up the answers and/or questions, how SFSE system would detect that?

Comment: if u feel it suspicious, u can flag it to moderators and add your comments while flagging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered a few times on different stackexchanges sites.

Quote:

> The system automatically detects suspicious voting patterns, but mods
>   also have tools to help them look into it manually. You can flag one
>   of the posts for mod attention and tell them what's up, and they'll
>   check to see if it was the same user voting on all of them and if that
>   user seems to be a sockpuppet

from: [Should we and how can we report suspected vote rigging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108369/should-we-and-how-can-we-report-suspected-vote-rigging)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Got what i have to do in these scenarios.